# Basic Operations Vocabulary

Tags: education

I have just moved to Australia for studying abroad. I am from Vietnam (non-speaking English country). While I am studying, I sometimes have problems with the teacher's way of expressing, especially in mathematical operations (plus, minus, divide, multiply, such as that if 2+2= 4, we say 2 plus 2 is equal to 4). Is there any sites to for the info on the Internet or books for this topics. I did make research for the vocabulary but I am afraid I will either lack word or learning imprecise words.

I can understand "2 plus 2 equals 4" is a correct way but cannot be sure other ways like "if 4 subtracted from 2 is 2" is a correct way or not.

Many thanks,

Comment: $4$ subtracted from $2$ is "$2-4$."  The "from" here means that you start with $2$ and $4$ is being subtracted.

Comment: Many thanks, Michael. But what I meant was if there is a website or standard textbook explaining or giving out vocabulary for addition, subtraction, and others, such as http://www.leeward.hawaii.edu/files/mathlab/handouts/Translating_Words_into_Algebra.pdf